# Why do people say STM32Cubemx is full of bugs?

Tags: stm32, stm32cubemx

I have worked with stm32cubemx for 2 years now, and I have found on forums people have mentioned that stm32cubemx is full of bugs? Why is that?

Comment: I have heard people on other forums saying that X is Y. But I won't show any source on this. You will have to trust me on this.

Comment: I once tryed to generate code with Cubemx for a new controller and not all peripherals of the controller could be enabled with cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People on the internet won't say something is free of bugs.

STM32CubeMX is a complicated bit of software that must support many things. It is actively maintained by ST, and therefore most bugs reported will be fixed.

Like most software, there will be bugs.

[STM32CubeMX Forum](https://community.st.com/s/topic/0TO0X000000BTr8WAG/stm32cubemx)

Comment: Sometimes it is not the CubeMX that has problems, sometimes it is the MCU firmware libraries (CubeF1, CubeF2, etc) that have issues. When this happens it is usually just better to rewrite say the I2C driver or the CEC driver than to wait for anyone to fix it. Sometimes the peripherals themselves have a weird interface, and sometimes the HAL driver for a peripheral has a weird interface, it's like nobody has thought how the peripheral will be used in an actual real life scenario.